# Create a blank record via PHP based on MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've got a home-grown LAMP app that uses the same HTML code for the "Modify record" and "New record" pages based on whether it is passed a blank record or a non-blank record. Currently, I'm creating the blank record by selecting a single record from the MySQL table and manually setting each field (by name) to NULL. There's got to be a better way to do this, but the search terms to find what I need are just too darn generic. I've looked at  using something like mysql_fetch_array or get_class_vars, but I just can't get them to work. Here's what I'm trying to replace with something a bit less manual:

```
// Select a row, any row... (using CodeIgniter)
$q = $this->db->get($this->config->item('db'),1);
// For each ... um ... one ... row, add it to $data
foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
// set each **KNOWN** field to NULL
$data[0]->column1 = NULL;
$data[0]->column2 = NULL;
...
```

I know it's a dirty hack, but it works. What's the "right" way to do this?

Comment: why are you making a blank row?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. What's the expected result of this code fragment and how to you intend to use it? Why don't you just create a stdClass object?

Comment: I'll try to clarify: I'm passing a record to an HTML form. If that record is non-blank, then the form assumes the user is editing an existing record. If that record is blank, then the form assumes the user is creating a new record. This allows me to have code like <?php echo $r->column1; ?> work for both scenarios instead of having two different batches of HTML code; one for "modify" and one for "new". This is all working fine. What I'm trying to avoid is having to manually create a new property or NULL out a new selected column every time I add a column to the database. Is that clearer?

Comment: Is the record number set manually or is it automaticly set via php/mysql?

Comment: Record number? I have an auto-incremented index column, but that gets set when the data is inserted into the table. Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are doing exactly this:

```php
$data[0] = (object) array_fill_keys($this->db->list_fields('your_table_name'), null);
```

Reference: [CI->db->list_fields()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/fields.html), [array_fill_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php), [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Ah ... I was looking for a general PHP solution and hadn't considered looking for a specific CodeIgniter solution. Thanks! For the sake of others who might stumble upon this question with the same question, is there a general PHP solution?

Comment: @JohnStraffin Well, general PHP solution will likely have to implement their own list_fields() of sorts. In case of MySQL it uses [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query, then iterates through results. Definitely not a one-line solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting 1 row only, you'd better off using ->row() method instead of a resuls() & useless foreach loop

e.g:

```
$row = $this->db->select('*')->from('table')->get()->row();
```

getting to your problem now, you'll have to define the fields you're using something like this

```
$fields = array('id', 'name', '...etc');
```

then you'll do something like this to get empty if not available

```
foreach ( $fields as $f ) $data[$f] = isset($row->$f) ? $row->$f : NULL;
```

this will make all fields available in your $data, so you can pass it to a view.

Comment: That manual $fields array() is what I'm trying to do away with ... is there no way to use the existing structure of the retrieved $row to dynamically build the $fields array() without knowing the column names ahead of time (or having to edit the manual $fields array() every time the table is altered)?

Comment: Also, thanks for the row() method hint. I knew there had to be a better way to do that as well, but had simply re-purposed some existing code to start the function and, since it worked, never went back and cleaned it up. :-)

Comment: You can use the list_fields method if you don't like to do it manually , something like this $fields = $this->db->list_fields('table_name');